# Limiting vertical camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen multiple threads on this topic, although none of those solutions have worked for my current script. I have my camera set up so it rotates when the right mouse button is being held down and dragged. My camera moves with the WASD keys.

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        // Get mouse origin
        mouseOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        isRotating = true;
    }

    if (isRotating)
    {
        Vector3 pos = cameraMain.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - mouseOrigin);

        transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.right, -pos.y * turnSpeed);
        transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, pos.x * turnSpeed);
    }
```

The error I have with this is that the camera vertically rotates freely. I want to know how to apply a limit to this rotation without changing the effect this code has on the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've redone my camera movement code. I have this running so it only calls this function when the right mouse button is being held down.

```
public float speed = 10.0F;
public float RotSpeed = 150.0F;
public float minY = 0.0f;
public float maxY = 90.0f;
float forwardBackward;
float leftRight;
float RotLeftRight;
float RotUpDown;
Vector3 euler;

public void CameraRotate()
{
    transform.localEulerAngles = euler;
    // Getting axes
    RotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    RotUpDown = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * -RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Doing movements
    euler.y += RotLeftRight;

    euler.x += RotUpDown;

    LimitRotation ();
}

public void LimitRotation()
{
    if(euler.x >= maxY)
        euler.x = maxY;
    if(euler.x <= minY)
        euler.x = minY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isRotating)
{
    Vector3 pos = cameraMain.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - mouseOrigin);

     pos.x =  Mathf.Clamp (pos.x, 0, 90);
     pos.y =  Mathf.Clamp (pos.y, 0, 90);

    transform.RotateAround("pass center object position", transform.right, -pos.y * turnSpeed);
    transform.RotateAround("pass center object position", Vector3.up, pos.x * turnSpeed);
}
```

Comment: This has no effect upon the camera.

Comment: is this script attached to camera.?

Comment: This script is attached to the camera and it is active. The Mathf.clamp statements just don't do anything.

Comment: add your center point. camera rotating arround which point/ object. see updated answer.

Comment: I've realized this modification has kept me from rotating downwards on the y-axis with the right mouse button.

Comment: You can user any value in **Mathf.Clamp()**. use -90 to 90 for up and down rotation. 0-90 up and 0-(-90) is down.

Comment: This method doesn't quite work for me, and I really don't know why. If i replace the zeros with -90 or -180, it just rotates freely.